# Wordpress on mobile devices with new data after updating page

Tags: cache, mobile

I work with a site where a weather report is displayed on the page. With each page refresh, some data changes. But no on mobile devices. Plugin for caching is disabled. There is a suspicion that this browser caches this information.

Page Details:
post type: page
Content: shortcode that gets information from another site.
Link to the [**page**](https://roeiverenigingbarendrecht.nl/rvb-weerstation/).

Any idea how to get a mobile device to show the new data on page refresh?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How is the content generated?  Also, on your phone, try to open the page in a PRIVATE tab to see if it updates.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis Content is generated via shortcode. That is, all the page content is one shortcode.